# Regex to modify a string is not working in Velocity Template

Tags: regex, apache, templates, velocity

I wrote a java code to read a velocity template file and print the output after a string manipulation.
The java code is given below

```
VelocityEngine velocity = new VelocityEngine();
velocity.init();
/*  next, get the Template  */
Template t = velocity.getTemplate( "./src/abc.vm" );
/*  create a context and add data */
VelocityContext context1 = new VelocityContext();
context.put("a", "200001");
context.put("b", "s12.1");
/* now render the template into a StringWriter */
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
t.merge(context, writer);

/* show the World */
System.out.println( writer.toString() );
```

The string manipulation logic is written in the template file as below.
abc.vm template content is given below.

```
#set($c = $b.replace("[^\\d.]"," "))
#set($appnd = "$c$a")
String After modification : $appnd
```

For this my desired output is

**String After modification :121200001**

but the string modification is not happening here. Currently the output getting is '**s12.1200001**'

The regex part is not working.Am I missing something?. Please help me to write a regex in velocity template for this string manipulation.

Comment: Use `$b.replaceAll`.

Comment: I have tried the replaceAll too but the regex worked in java code didn't worked properly in velocity template.

Comment: Yes, because you used `\\d`. You must use `\d`.

Comment: Its worked .... Thanks!!!